# How to share google compute engine images across projects?

Tags: google-compute-engine

[From documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/overview) I know that images are global resources that *"are accessible by any resource in any zone within the same project"*.

I am looking for a functionality similar to sharing AMIs within AWS. That is, I create an image, make it public and anyone can use it immediately.

How to best achieve something similar in GCE? The problem is that the image I need to create would be large - around 100GB. So I am looking for a way of sharing the image that wouldn't involve slow copying (e.g. from a bucket in google cloud storage).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use Google Cloud Storage, but then you will be charged every time it will be downloaded, and it will take long time (if it is 100 GB).

The better solution is to give the user "Can view" access to your project. Then user can create a instance using your image, using `gcloud` command line. But be aware, that user will see all that you have in the project, he just won't be able to change it.

This solution is faster, if the owner of the image, has used it in the zone, you want to use. Because the image is cashed there, and it will start instantaneously. Another plus is, that owner doesn't get charged if someone downloads this image.

```
`gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME]
    --image-family [IMAGE_FAMILY]
    --image-project [IMAGE_PROJECT]
    --machine_type=<type-of-machine> 
    --network="default"
    --family my-image-family`
```

If you want to give access to a larger group of people, you can create a Google group, allow group members "Can view" access to the project. Now you can control who can access it, using your Google group.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your image into Google Cloud Storage. Google Cloud storage gives you even more options to control who has access to the image besides just making it public.

You can use gcutil to access that image. Something like
`gcutil --project=project-name-1 addimage "my-awesome-image" gs://bucket-name/myawesome.images.gz`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's good to have it documented! However, as I said in the question, I am specifically looking for an efficient solution of sharing *large* images and I already did consider the Google Cloud Storage option.

Answer (score 1):

Compute Engine as added an IAM role (Compute.imageUser) that allows sharing images with other projects.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects

Disclaimer - I work for Google Cloud.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 1):

One can simply grand `roles/compute.imageUser` access to a service account of `<ID-of-your-project>` that is used for creating instances:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <ID-of-image-owners-project> \
  --member serviceAccount:account-to-create-instances@<ID-of-your-project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/compute.imageUser
```