# Export GCP (Google Cloud Platform) Image

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I have multiple GCP (Google Cloud Platform) accounts and would like to copy an Image from one account to another.  I see options for exporting and importing an linux VM, but my Images are Windows.

Comment: Is it between accounts or projects?

Comment: both, I have 2 different accounts, each having their own project

Comment: This should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883313/how-to-share-google-compute-engine-images-across-projects Play with the IAM Roles. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects

Answer (score 0):

Why not store in Google Cloud Storage and yes use IAM to provide access. If both Google Cloud Projects are part of one Google Cloud Organization you can set a policy at the Organization level and apply to the Projects.