# How to share Google Cloud images with *other* users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, sharing

I setup a VM on Google Cloud Compute for my students, saved an Image.  As per instructions on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#granting_a_user_access_to_images, I granted my students "Compute Image User" access to the Project that was used to create that Image. So they see that my Project as available, and they can click to select it...

But when they try to actually create their own compute instances to do their calculations, they get told "You don't have permission to view the instances in this project".

On AWS all I have to do is save a public AMI and then point other people to it. It's so easy... What is the appropriate analog on Google Cloud Compute?

I've already seen this post: "[How to share google compute engine images across projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883313/how-to-share-google-compute-engine-images-across-projects)" but it only pointed me to the very documents I've been reading already.

**EDIT:** My students are able to execute "gcloud config set project [my project]" to my project, however, when they run "gcloud compute images list --project [my project]" for the same project, it says "- Failed to find project [my project]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing users with the role "Compute Image User"  allows users to access images from another project, but it doesn’t allow those users to view or create instances or other resources in that project.

It should however allow the users to whom you have assigned the role access to the images located in your project, but critically from their own project.

I understand your students have tried running the following command without success:

```
gcloud compute images list --project [IMAGE_PROJECT]
```

My suggestion at this point would be to ensure they are using your Project ID in replace of `[IMAGE_PROJECT]`, rather than your project name.

Your project ID can be retrieved by clicking on the drop down menu at the top of your Console, and the project ID information can be seen to the right of your project name.

Similarly, they should be able to create an instance in their own project from the image in your project, by running the following command:

```
gcloud compute instances create MYINSTANCE --image [IMAGE_NAME] --image-project [IMAGE_PROJECT] --project [PROJECT_ID]
```

Where `[IMAGE_NAME]` is the name of the image in your project, `[IMAGE_PROJECT]` is where the project where the image is located and `[PROJECT_ID]` is the project ID where you want to create the instance.

This is also possible in the Developers Console. When creating the Virtual Machine you can change the boot disk and then click on “Custom Images” and select the project where the image is located. Once you select the project, all of the images for that project will be displayed.

If you would like your students to be able to view instances in your own project, you would need to assign them a role with greater scope than the “Compute Image User” role.

For example you could assign them the “Compute Viewer” role which would allow them to view your Compute Engine resources, including your instances/images.

This can be achieved by following these steps:

1. Hover over “IAM & admin” and select “IAM” from the submenu.
2. Click on “ADD” at the top of the page
3. In the new “Add members” window, add the Google account email address for the users or group you would like to assign the role to
4. In the “Roles” drop down menu under “Compute Engine” select “Compute Viewer”
5. Click “ADD” to add the new role to the user/group

Alternatively, if you would like your students to be able to create instances in your project, you could assign them the “Compute Instance Admin” role by following the above steps and substituting “Compute Viewer” for “Compute Instance Admin (v1)”.

Comment: Sorted this out via Hangout w/ @neilH today: After granting the permissions he describes, I was having users being greeted by an empty home directory.  On AWS, the default user is "ubuntu" so I was accustomed to everyone landing in the same directory, but on Google Cloud, it creates a home directory depending on your login name -- and note: if your Google username is different from your local (e.g. Mac Terminal) username, then *you* can end up in different home directories.  Recommend that users try "ls -lt /home" upon login to get their bearings.